# how to set multi background color for vicotory chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, victory-charts

I'm using Victory Chart to draw some chart, but now i facing some problem about color in victory chart, the color will be like this
[image]

And like this [image]

Here is my codesandbox trying to archive these chart
https://codesandbox.io/s/chart-7-bj1dj?file=/src/App.js

Please help, i search for whole documentation and example but no luck, thank you so much

Comment: have you found a solution to this problem?